# Handling window onclose function from flash

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a html popup containing one flash file. Onclose of the popup I need to write some values into the socket. How can I handle the onclose event from flash ?

Thanks
Binoy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try handling the onclose event from javascript and call flash from javascript using [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).addCallback.

Careful when setting up your html document for ExternalInterface though.

Comment: The "careful" bit, I guess, refers to the fact that you need to allow actionscript-javascript communication when embedding the SWF file, by setting the allowScriptAccess embed parameter to true. :)

Comment: yes, that and making sure embed tag's id attribute and object tag's name attribute are the same. Some browsers access the swf via the embed tag, others use the object tag, so careful with that too. If it doesn't work in firefox and IE for example, look for that pitfall